# Interface or type-hint for single object and multiple object class in php

Tags: php, oop

Recently started working with OOP in PHP. Following the "code to an Interface" principle, i got confused as to the type hint to use when passing a single object or multiple as argument to a method.

Currently, i have a "Student" class - represents a row in my students table, i also have a "Students" class that holds multiple student objects in an array.
To fetch the profile of one student, i pass the Students object (holding a single student object) to the profile class. I set a Students type hint in the profile class.

Now i feel this is bad code as i have lines like this

`student = new Students();`
and `students = new Students();`

question is,

am i on the right path?

if i remove the Students class and work with Student alone, based on the principle, how do i pass multiple Student objects (assuming array) to the profile class if it accepts a Student type hint?

what options do i have?

Thanks.

Comment: Why using Students Class,you can only add array of Student in your Profil class directly

Comment: do you mean i change the student type hint in the profile class constructor to array instead.

Comment: like from this __construct (Student $student) to this __construct (Array $student)

Comment: How does fetching the profile of multiple students look like? Is that even defined? Does it return multiple profiles?

Comment: when the profile class receives a single or collection of student objects, it iterates and picks the ID of each, then fetches profiles from the DB and returns multiple objects - one profile for each student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by `Students` you mean a collection of `Student` objects, perhaps a better name would be `StudentCollection` or `StudentSet`.

There are two ways around the type hint problem:

1. Introduce a method on `StudentCollection` called `->getProfiles()`; it would return an array of profiles for each `Student` instance it's managing by calling methods on `Profile`.
2. Introduce a (static) method on `Profile` that operates on a `StudentCollection` instance.

*The first option has [feature envy](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/feature-envy), which is why I've included a workaround.*

Comment: i will work with the second option, this means i would be using the StudentCollection to represent single or multiple students and pass this collection to other modules in my app. Is that ok? also why is the method static? i intend to return profile objects for each student, ie ParentProfile or Medicalprofile

Comment: I figured a static would make sense for a method that returns an instance of the class it's defined in. Otherwise you would have to call it ProfileFactory.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel you might want to try [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or at least take a look at its architecture.

I'm not sure if I get your exact issue... But if you want to go for your own code I would first abstract the DB layer as well and have some base classes like Database, Table, Row, Field that an describe the DB stack and extend them as needed with some magic methods. So when you do Student extends Table it would automatically check for a "students" table or whatever else convention you like to implement. Alternatively you could just pass the table name as arg.

Whatever Object is returning the result set from the database would have to construct a single Row object for each row and add it to a collection of rows that I would name ResultSet and contains all the row objects and return that collection.

Comment: my DB abstraction is in Yii DAO, i fetch a single row, instantiate a Student class then pass it to Profile Class. Now if i fetch multiple rows and use this ResultSet to instantiate multiple objects, how do i pass that to Profile.